# How to specify common string for version in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I have a build.gradle that has following content:-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

How can I specify the version number (here 25.3.1) at a common place and reuse it every where, so that when ever I need to change it, I have to change it at only one place?

Comment: I dont think they should be shared. You should explicitly set each version against them, by design

Comment: @Selvin I didnt know that they could be replaced with variables, that is why I posted the question here. I was not sure about the term, I did try googling but couldn't find solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Gradle features to achieve this.

```
ext {
    supportVersion = "25.3.1"
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
}
```

See also:

- https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Comment: My bad for copying original source, edited to doubles.

Answer (score 3):

In Project level gradle, you specify the version code. If we specify version code in project level then we can use that version in all modules. For example, we had three modules in a project. If we specify version code in project level then easily use that in module level gradle file.

```
ext {
    appcompatVersion = '25.3.1'
    supportDesignVersion = '25.3.1'
    cardviewVersion = '25.3.1'
    recyclerviewVersion = '25.3.1' 
}
```

In Module level gradle, you use it like below:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appcompatVersion'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:$supportDesignVersion'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:$cardviewVersion'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerviewv7:$recyclerviewVersion'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the project gradle file add the variable

```
  buildscript {
     ext.supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.1"

     dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
          ........
```

And in the app gradle file refer the variable created.

```
  dependencies {
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
      compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

for more reference follow [this](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/gradle-configure-variables-for-all-android-project-modules-in-one-place-5a6e56cd384e) link